# How can I use generics to convert a TValue from a dictionary into a List<TValue>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, dictionary

First, I'm new to generics, so I apologize in advance for any mistake.

I would like to be able to compare different types of dictionaries in a unified way.
I to compare 2 dictionaries that might have this type (just to be clear I want to compare 2 different dictionaries that have the same type):

```
Dictionary<string, Int32>
Dictionary<Int32, Int32>
Dictionary<string, string>
Dictionary<string, List<Int32>>
Dictionary<Int32, List<Int32>>
Dictionary<Int32, List<ComplexObject>>
```

Using generics, I got to this code:

```
 private static bool DictionaryEquals<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> left, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> right)
    {
        var comp = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
        if (left.Count != right.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var pair in left)
        {
            TValue value;
            if ((typeof(TValue).Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic"))
            {
                TValue rightValue;
                right.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out rightValue);
                return ListEquals<TValue>(new List<TValue>(pair.Key), rightValue);
            }

            if (right.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value) || (!comp.Equals(pair.Value, value)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static bool ListEquals<TValue>(List<TValue> left, List<TValue> right)
    {
        if (left.Count != right.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return left.All(right.Contains);
    }
```

I'm having problems calling the ListEquals method, I don't know how to pass in the pair.key and rightValue parameters.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Do you need check equality of both keys and values of dictionaries?

Comment: Your function won't return false if there is a key in the left dictionary that's not in the right dictionary.  (It only checks the other way around.)

Comment: Yes, I need to check both keys and values.

Comment: If the count is the same it is enough to check the keys in one dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code and this is working one, but I don't know how to replace `dynamic`, which is not best choiсe, but solves all casting problems.

```
        private static bool DictionaryEquals<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> left, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> right)
        {
            var comp = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
            if (left.Count != right.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(TValue).IsGenericType && typeof(TValue).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            {
                return left.All(pair => right.ContainsKey(pair.Key) && ListEquals((dynamic)pair.Value, (dynamic)right[pair.Key]));            
            }
            else
            {
                return left.All(pair => right.ContainsKey(pair.Key) && comp.Equals(pair.Value, right[pair.Key]));
            }
        }

        private static bool ListEquals<TValue>(List<TValue> left, List<TValue> right)
        {
            if (left.Count != right.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return left.All(right.Contains);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `TValue` is type of rightValue, than TValue is a `List<SomeType>`. But use ListEquals, not `List<SomeValue>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the problem:

```
private static bool DictionaryEquals<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> left, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> right)
{
    var comp = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    if (left.Count != right.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (left.Keys.Intersect(right.Keys).Count() != left.Count)
        return false;
        //there is a key in the left dictionary that's not in the right dictionary
        //if there are any keys in the right dictionary not in the left then either 
        //there is one in the left not in the right as well, or the counts won't have 
        //been equal, so we know the two key sets are equal.

    var defaultValueComparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;

    Func<TValue, TValue, bool> valueComparer;

    if (typeof(TValue) is IEnumerable)
        valueComparer = (first, second) => ((IList)first).SequenceEqual((IList)second);
    else
        valueComparer = (first, second) => defaultValueComparer.Equals(first, second);

    foreach (var key in left.Keys)
    {
        if (!valueComparer(left[key], right[key]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static bool SequenceEqual(this IList first, IList second)
{
    if (first.Count != second.Count)
        return false;

    IEnumerator iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator(),
                iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator();

    while (true)
    {
        bool next1 = iterator1.MoveNext();
        bool next2 = iterator2.MoveNext();
        // Sequences aren't of same length. We don't 
        // care which way round. 
        if (next1 != next2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Both sequences have finished - done 
        if (!next1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!object.Equals(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few important points to note:

Rather than having the two sets be a "set comparison" I had them be a sequence comparison.  If they really should have a set comparison then it would make more sense for them to be something other than lists in the first place.  Regardless, if that's an important change you can modify the name and implementation of my `SequenceEqual` method to the following:

```
public static bool SetEquals(this IList first, IList second)
{
    if (first.Count != second.Count)
        return false;

    return first.OfType<object>().Intersect(second.OfType<object>())
        .Count() < first.Count;
}
```

Rather than determining how to compare the values inside of the foreach it makes sense to do it outside; the type of the value won't change in the loop.  Determine what the comparison function will be once and then just call it over and over again.  Delegates are great for this.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this do?

```
public class DictionaryEqualityComparer<TKey,TValue> : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>>
{
    public bool Equals( Dictionary<TKey , TValue> x , Dictionary<TKey , TValue> y )
    {
        bool unequal =  x.Count != y.Count
                     || x.Except( y ).Any() // this is probably redundant
                     || y.Except( x ).Any() // but my caffiene titration is off this AM
                     ;
        return !unequal ; 
    }
    public int GetHashCode( Dictionary<TKey , TValue> obj )
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode() ;
    }
```

for a couple of reasons. The biggest one being that two dictionaries of the same type, say `Dictionary<string,Widget>` can use different equality comparers for the keys. In the instance of a string key, it might be any one of the stock `StringComparer` implementations. This complicates the notion of "equality."